# Spring Boot Cors "Access-Control-Max-Age" header is ignored by browsers

Tags: spring-boot, cors, http-headers

What I am expecting from this header is; browser sending only one `options pre-flight request` for the *max-age duration per resource*.

However, every browser that I tried keeps sending `options pre-flight request` for **every request** even the ones that are sent before.

I tried disabling `no-cache header` but nothing changed. I shared my `cors config` code *below*. By the way, my spring boot is *not configured* for https/ssl but domain and front-end react app **is**, could that be the problem?

```
   @Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer(){
        return new WebMvcConfigurer()  {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry.addMapping("/**")
                        .allowedHeaders("*")
                        .allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "PUT", "PATCH", "DELETE", "OPTIONS")
                        .allowCredentials(true)
                        .allowedOrigins(ALLOWED_ORIGINS)
                        .exposedHeaders(AuthorizationController.AUTHENTICATION_KEY_NAME,
                                        RequestInterceptor.FAILURE_REASON_HEADER_KEY_NAME,
                                        RequestInterceptor.CONTENT_DISPOSITION_HEADER_KEY_NAME)
                        .maxAge(36000);
            }
        };
    }
@Bean
        public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
            CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
            configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Collections.singletonList(ALLOWED_ORIGINS));
            configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET", "POST", "PUT", "PATCH", "DELETE", "OPTIONS"));
            configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Collections.singletonList("*"));
            configuration.setExposedHeaders(Arrays.asList(AuthorizationController.AUTHENTICATION_HEADER_NAME,
                                                        RequestInterceptor.ERROR_DESCRIPTION_HEADER_KEY_NAME,
                                                        RequestInterceptor.CONTENT_DISPOSITION_HEADER_KEY_NAME));
            UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
            source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
            return source;
        }
```

**I am also adding below headers to every request in `OncePerRequestFilter`.**

```
httpServletResponse.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age","36000");
httpServletResponse.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin",ALLOWED_ORIGINS);
httpServletResponse.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers","*");
httpServletResponse.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods","GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, HEAD, OPTIONS");
httpServletResponse.setHeader("Cache-Control","no-cache, no-store, max-age=36000")
```

Answer (score -1):

you need to white list the domain/host from which you are hitting the back-end/